# Не показывать выпадающие подсказки при фокусе на поле ввода

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Собственно сабж. Yandex Maps Js Api при использовании suggestView если инпут не пустой, как сдалать так, чтобы при фокусе на поле с адресом или при изменении значения этого поля скриптом, не появлялась выпадающая подсказка, а появлялась, к примеру, только после нажатия хотя бы одной клавиши.

Comment: Возможно, проще будет не использовать сам SuggestView,а делать запрос к suggest https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/suggest.html?lang=ru только по тем событиям, которые нужны

Comment: Если вариант из ответа или комментария не подходят, уточните сценарий и приведите минимальный рабочий пример кода.

Comment: @shchedrin спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Как быстрый "костыль" можно использовать параметр **[offset](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView.html#SuggestView__param-options.offset)** для сдвига выпадающего списка за пределы видимости. Перед заполнением поля скриптом сдвигайте подсказки в сторону, а при нажатии клавиатуры возвращайте в нулевую позицию.

```
suggestView.options.set('offset', [0,-2000])
```

Или можно также через опции задавать саджесту несуществующий [провайдер](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView.html#SuggestView__param-options.provider), а при ручном вводе переопределять его заново:

```
suggestView.options.set('provider', 'none')
...
suggestView.options.set('provider', 'yandex#map')
```

Comment: спасибо, второе более элегантное решение )